# PyTorch: Image dimension issue

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, machine-learning, python-imaging-library, pytorch

I am working on an image classifier dataset. There are 31 classes in my dataset and there is a folder for each class. For training, I am loading data in the following manner:

```
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torch

def load_training(root_path, dir, batch_size, kwargs):
    transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.Resize([256, 256]),
         transforms.RandomCrop(224),
         transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
         transforms.ToTensor()])
    data = datasets.ImageFolder(root=root_path + dir, transform=transform)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, drop_last=True, **kwargs)
    return train_loader
```

Now for a batch size 32, each batch dim are : `[32,3,224,224]`. I know *Pytorch* uses *PIL* for loading images. But when I'm trying to load images from a list named `images` of size 32 using PIL using the following code snippet:

```
for i in images:
    im = Image.open(root_dir + dir + i)
    im = im.convert('RGB')
    im.load()
    im = im.resize((224, 224))
    im = np.asarray( im, dtype="int32" )
    print(im.shape)
    temp_im_2 = torch.from_numpy(np.array(temp_im)).float()
```

It says `im.shape` is `(32,224,224,3)`. What am I doing wrong? What should I do to get the batches to be of the same shape in both cases say `[32,3,224,224]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just swapping axes? Like `im.transpose(0, 3, 1, 2)` if `im` has four dimensions. However, `im.shape` should return `(224, 224, 3)` as you've loaded only one image, so that `im.transpose(2, 0, 1)` should give you the image with the channels in the first dimension which you can then stack together to form a batch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.transpose` you should use `im.permute()` it takes multiple dim to swap.
In your case, it is `im.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)`

Comment: If `im` is a `torch.Tensor`, `im.permute` is indeed the correct function. However, his variable is an `np.ndarray`.